# Display photos with ALAsset

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

```
ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock groupsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([groupName compare:[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]] == NSOrderedSame){
        self.assetsGroup = group;
        NSLog(@"Has found the target group");
        return ;
    }
    ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if (result) {
            [self.assets addObject:result];
            NSLog(@"%@",self.assets);
        }
    };
    ALAssetsFilter *onlyPhotosFilter = [ALAssetsFilter allPhotos];
    [self.assetsGroup setAssetsFilter:onlyPhotosFilter];
    [self.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetsEnumerationBlock];
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
    NSString *errorMessage = nil;
    switch ([error code]) {
        case ALAssetsLibraryAccessUserDeniedError:
        case ALAssetsLibraryAccessGloballyDeniedError:
            errorMessage = @"The user has declined access to it.";
            break;
        default:
            errorMessage = @"Reason unknown.";
            break;
    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                   message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",errorMessage]
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
};

NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupAlbum | ALAssetsGroupEvent | ALAssetsGroupFaces | ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos;
[self.library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:groupTypes
                            usingBlock:groupsEnumerationBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];
```

I want to display photos in a particular album in a collectinView.I can get the Data inside the enumerationBlock,but can't use self.assets to display a collection.I'm not very familiar with blocks.How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To display `ALAssets` in a `UIImageView`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  ALAsset *asset = [self.assets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *image = [[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage];

  [cell.imageView setImage:image]

  return cell;
}
```

If you call `[self.collectionView reloadData]` after locating the desired assets, you should be good to go.

Comment: Where should I call [self.collectionView reloadData]? I called it after         [self.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetsEnumerationBlock];
 and in viewDidLoad but both fail to display

Comment: I'm location assets in ```awakeFromNib:``` and my reloading my collection view after ```[self.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetsEnumerationBlock];```. It's hard to tell why this is failing without looking at when you are loading your assets, and how your UICollectionViewDatasource is looking... If you are able to add assets to self.assets, you should be able to reload your collection view and display them after you are done locating them.